# How to add an entitlement to my iOS app to quickly test that it works before requesting Apple

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I want to test adding an entitlement to my iOS app called "MyApp". For instance lets say following is the entitlement:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.networking.gamecenter</key>
    <true/>
```

I add the above to my `.entitlements` file. But the moment I do that Xcode starts complaining stating the following error.

```
Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "MyApp" target's entitlements.
Automatic signing can't add the com.apple.developer.networking.gamecenter entitlement to your provisioning profile. Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a matching provisioning profile from the developer website. Alternatively, to continue using automatic signing, remove this entitlement from your entitlements file and its associated functionality from your code.
```

I understand the error. It wants me to add the entitlement to my provisioning profile by going into the developer website. But is it not even possible to test my code by adding the entitlement before even I request Apple to grant the entitlement to me? This is really strange. I firstly want to test my code and see whether adding the entitlement works for my app or not.

Comment: A developer account is required for using entitlements, you should register on apple and create an AppId with the bundle identifier you are using

Comment: I already have a apple developer account. I also have my app on Testflight for beta testing. But I simply wanted to try an entitlement before requesting it to Apple. Just wanted to try locally by editing the entitlements plist file and run the app and test if it works.

Comment: I think that when adding capabilities through Xcode 'Signing & Capabilities' screen, the AppId and provisioning profile are modified automatically, without having to go to Apple website

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=0oi77447, you don't need the entitlements for running on iOS Simulator but you will need it for physical devices

Answer (score 1):

You won't need the entitlement for testing on iOS/iPadOS Simulator but for read devices, you will need to request the entitlement. You can request it here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/networking-multicast

Source: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=0oi77447